# Lebesgue Measurable meaning

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that a function is measurable if the set $\{x \in X: f(x)>a \} \in \Sigma$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$ where $\Sigma$ is the sigma algebra of $X$.

But what does it mean to be Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: It means a integral can be assigned to the function.

Comment: "Lebesgue measurable function " is the special case of your definition where we take $\Sigma$ to be the sigma-algebra of Lebesgue-measurable sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Omega,\Omega'$ be two sets equipped with some sigma algebras $A$ and $A'$. Then a function $f: \Omega \to \Omega'$ is called $A$-$A'$ measurable, if $\forall M' \in A': f^{-1}(M') \in A$.

According to this Lebesgue measurable is the case $\Omega' = \mathbb{R}$, with $A'$ being the sigma algebra of Borel sets (smallest sigmal algebra that contains all open sets) and $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ with $A$ being the sigma algebra of Lebesgue sets (completion of the Borel sigma algebra, which means it contains any subsets of sets with measure zero).

Then there is a lemma that says a function $f: X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{ + \infty, - \infty \}$ is Lebesgue measurable if and only if $f^{-1}([-\infty,a])$ is contained in the Lebesgue sigma algebra for any $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. (alternatively you can take the preimage of $[-\infty,a),(a,\infty],[a,\infty]$)

Moreover you need to be careful saying $\Sigma$ is **the** sigma algebra of $X$. Usually you can equip $X$ with a few different sigma algebras. Edit: the same applies to the term measurable.

Comment: A word of caution: If $f:R\to R$ is a  Lebesgue-measurable  function and $ B$ is  a Borel set then $f^{-1}B$ is a Lebesgue set but $f^{-1}A$ may fail to be a Lebesgue set for some Lebesgue set $A$.